# How can I make all the text in an InDesign document black using ExtendScript?

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript

Here is my attempt:

```
function makeAllTextBlack() {
  var document = app.activeDocument,
    textFrames = document.textFrames,
    nbTextFrames = textFrames.length,
    swatch = document.swatches.item("C=100 M=100 Y=100 K=100"),
    i;
  for (i = 0; i < nbTextFrames; i +=1) {
      textFrames[i].fillColor = swatch;
  }
}

makeAllTextBlack();
```

When running this script in the ExtendScript Toolkit, it complains that the value defined for the `fillColor` property is incorrect, saying that it expected a Swatch or a String but received nothing. Is there something wrong with my swatch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The swatch you get that way is invalid, even if you try to get it by name (itemByName) don't ask me why, but it is better to use Color objects. For example you could do this to create the color:

```
var color = document.colors.itemByName("myblack");
if(color==null){
    color = document.colors.add();
    color.name = "myblack";
    color.colorValue = [100,100,100,100];
}
```

Then apply it directly to the fillColor property.

(one remark, textFrames.fillColor will not change the texts color, but the TextFrame background... I think you want to iterate the texts on each TextFrame and change their fillColor.)

Answer (score 1):

Using the color objects seems to fix the issue :

```
function makeAllTextBlack() {
        var doc, blackColor;
        if( !app.documents.length ){ return; }

        doc = app.activeDocument;
        blackColor = doc.colors.itemByName ( "fullBlack" );
        if ( !blackColor.isValid )
        { 
            blackColor = doc.colors.add( {colorSpace:ColorSpace.CMYK, model:ColorModel.PROCESS, colorValue:[100,100,100,100], name:"fullBlack"} );
        }
        try
        {
            doc.stories.everyItem().fillColor = blackColor;
            alert("done");
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            alert(e+" "+e.line);
        }
    }

    makeAllTextBlack();
```

Hope it helps,

Loic